# How do I use Hashed Passwords with SETAPDF's Password Protected PDFs?

Tags: php, encryption, hash, password-hash, setapdf

I am using an API called [SET-PDF Stamper](https://www.setasign.com/products/setapdf-stamper/details/)

Our passwords use a hash and I am trying to use the hashed passwords with the setasign PDF api. In the documentation I see they support encryption but I can't find anything on hashing. Is there any way to implement their password protection on the document verifying the password hash?

Our hash uses the following `password_hash("password", CRYPT_BLOWFISH, $options);` Normally you would use password verify in this situation but I don't see a way to implement it with the setasign api.

Comment: Is it impossible to get the input from user, hash it, and then use that hash as a password, both when creating the file and when opening?

Comment: Your question is a little hard to follow; so you have a PDF file that is encrypted, that  you need to decrypt before your PHP can edit the file?

Comment: Have you tried [**reading the SET-PDF manual**](https://manuals.setasign.com/setapdf-core-manual/standard-encryption/)?. It shows you exactly how to open an encrypted PDF, if you have the original password. If you do not have the original password, then you can't access the PDF for editing (stamping).

Comment: @martin sorry about that, I have passwords that are hashed but I want to use this api to create a password protected pdf using that hashed password. I hope that clears up what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: @g4ost you should not use a hash as a password. Especially if the hash is of a genuine password!

Comment: @Martin Yes, I have read the manuals but my passwords that I am using from the database are hashed. When a user enters it in the password field it won't match the hashed password, it looks like seta-pdf only supports password encryption but doesn't state anything regarding password hashing.

Comment: @HoldOffHunger It's not possible to verify the hash when creating and opening the pdf file? Are there any alternative secure options that I could do?

Comment: Hi, g4st: I'm not sure that using a hash password is ideal for encrypting a pdf.  But, why would it not be possible to verify the hash?  hash('hello') = 123 today, and tomorrow, and the next day, doesn't it?  (or whatever the numbers are)  If you encrypt with a hash, just decrypt with the same hash, and you can make that hash with a password, anywhere, anytime, if you have the password, etc..

Comment: g4st: I should mention, HASHING is ONE-WAY.  You cannot "verify" a hash, without the original data.  Maybe you're mistaking HASHING with ENCRYPTION?

Comment: @HoldOffHunger you are incorrect re the repetitive nature of hashes; what about salts. Each and every password hash uses salts, to avoid the repetition that you illustrate here. Therefore the same password will give numerous hashes because of the salts.

Comment: @g4ost ; if you want a password protected PDF then the user themselves should set a password into a from input you can then use as a plaintext encryption key. If the user wants to use the same password you have as a DB hash, or not, that's their choice, not yours to make.

Comment: @g4ost if YOU want to make that choice for the user, simply manaully set a password (ie their username for example or some other plaintext value) and use that -- simple, and easy.

Comment: @Martin: A salt is not a hash.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)

Comment: @HoldOffHunger There API doesn't show a way to verify the hash when opening the pdf file from what I saw in the documentation. Also what I meant by verifying the hash is using password_verify($password, $password_hash) to determine if it's a correct password. That's currently how the login system works. In order for the pdf part to work am I going to have to resort to making encrypted passwords instead of hashing? Also wouldn't that be less secure than using a hash?

Comment: @HoldOffHunger ; Thank you; I am well aware of salt and hash. A hash with PHP `password_hash` is generated with a password plaintext and a salt. This means the same plaintext creates many different hashes with this method. This means your earlier comment about hash repetition does not hold here.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is not related to SetaPDF but you are searching for a feature in the PDF format, which is simply not available. You want a securtiy handler, that hashes the input before it is used to calculate the encryption key. That's simply not part of standard PDF encryption.

The standard PDF encryption algorithms start with a plain text password.

There's nothing you can do about it but writing your own logic for a PDF viewer (e.g. pdf.js) to modify the input (hash it) before it is passed to the algorithm that calculates the encryption key.

Comment: I have been looking into it and instead of hashing passwords in our db should we be using encryption? That way at least we could decrypt to use on the manuals that are password protected. That's the only solution I see working.

Comment: I'm not sure if you really want to know the passwords of your users? You may simply re-ask for the password, verify it against your saved hash+salt combination and if this is fine use it for encrypting the PDF document with it. This way the user password is only known to you for a short time and there's no need to save it on your end. Another way would be a separate password for the PDF encryption which is completely under your sole control so that it is not mixed with any other personal passwords of a user.

Comment: Yes, however, there doesn't seem to be a way to verify it through SETASIGN's API. There is no way for me to verify the hash using that API.

Comment: Why and what do you want to verifiy with SetaPDF? Aren't you storing the hash+salt? If this matches the passed password, just use the password for encrypting the PDF.